# I have a package which has 10 class files, would like to run first 6 class files in parallel and rest 4 in sequential how do you that?

Tags: testng, testng.xml

I have a package which has 10 class files, would like to run first 6 class files in parallel and rest 4 in sequential how do you that?

Comment: You need to provide more details, better to be a minimal reproducible code/repo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run TestNG groups both sequentially and in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288952/run-testng-groups-both-sequentially-and-in-parallel)

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I can provide one simple solution that might work in this case

Create 2 separate suite files, one for parallel tests and one for sequential tests

e.g

testng_parallel.xml

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel test" parallel="classes" thread-count="6">
    <test name="Test Grouping">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.testngpractice.A"></class>
            <class name="com.testngpractice.B"></class>
            <class name="com.testngpractice.C"></class>
            <class name="com.testngpractice.D"></class>
            <class name="com.testngpractice.E"></class>
            <class name="com.testngpractice.F"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

testng_sequential.xml

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Sequential tests" >
    <test name="Test Grouping">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.testngpractice.G"></class>
            <class name="com.testngpractice.H"></class>
            <class name="com.testngpractice.I"></class>
            <class name="com.testngpractice.J"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Then create a common testng file to run both these suites

testng.xml

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="All  tests">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="testng_parallel.xml" />
        <suite-file path="testng_sequential.xml" />
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Please replace the `class` name and `suite-file` path according to your project and this solution will solve your question.